How realistic is the common boat on a lake/a river problem?
The concept here is the relative motion in Newtonian physics.

A boat can travel at a maximum speed of $5 \frac{m}{s}$ in still lake. The boat enters a river. The water in the river travels on its own at $1 \frac{m}{s}$. What are the speeds of the boat downstream and upstream relative the banks of the river?

We have all done problems like that at the start of our physics journeys. And we all know that the answers people are looking for are $ 6 \frac{m}{s}$ and $ 4 \frac{m}{s}$.
I started wondering... Is it really the case that downstream and upstream speeds are $ 6 \frac{m}{s}$ and $ 4 \frac{m}{s}$? The water is flowing around the boat. The boat propeller in the river is interacting with chaotic water in the river rather than still water in the lake. Is modeling this scenario with simple vector addition a realistic approach?

Like any other physics simplification, it works reasonably well in many cases. A rowboat on the Mississippi - no problem. A kayak in class V white water - not so much.

A model reflects reality depending on how good it is. If you define the water as moving at 1m/s and the boat as moving at 5 m/s, then the boat moves upstream or downstream at 4 and 6m/s - by definition. If there's some real effect not captured by the model that makes the boat move slower or faster than 5m/s relative to the water, then your model will be wrong to some extent. We have no idea if the stated speed of 5m/s reflects reality or not. In reality, it's effectively impossible that the boat always travels at exactly 5m/s, but it can be "close enough".

Re, "The water is flowing around the boat." In the model that underlies the question, water flows around the boat at precisely 5 m/s in the lake and, at precisely 5 m/s in the river. "Water flowing around the boat" and "boat travelling through the water" both mean exactly the same thing. Likewise, if we turn off the motor and just drift with the river current at 1 m/s, then according to the model, a person on board the boat would see the river water as "still."

The boat is in the reference frame of the river.  If a thick fog rolled in and obscured both banks of the river, you would have no way of knowing that the water was actually flowing relative to the river banks.

Depends on the river. If the boat is near the middle of a wide deep river then the calculation is accurate. This is because the water near such a boat is just like lake water in the reference frame in which that water would be at rest in the absence of the boat. It is just as if someone had taken a bit of lake and made it move along, and then the boat moves relative to that water.
If the river is narrow or shallow then all sorts of other complications arise, as your question suggests. Turbulence in particular will change the answer a lot.

Yes. Physics models are about abstraction. This problem, as presented, requires a one dimensional lake and a one dimensional laminar river, with a point-like boat:
$$-4 = 1-5 $$
$$6 =  1 + 5 $$
in whatever units the problem used.
In an engineering treatment, or generalized physics treatment where the boat moves at $v$, and the river, $u$, you could include turbulence changing the drag or prop-efficiency. There's a power consideration, since up (down) river is also up (down) vs $U(h) = mgh$, or more generally:
$$ U(h) = G\frac{M_{\oplus}m}{R_{\oplus}+h} $$
And if your river is quasar jet, maybe you need to add rapidities instead of velocities with:
$$ \tanh^{-1} v_{\pm} = \tanh^{-1} v \pm \tanh^{-1} u $$
and whatever else you can think of.
